# Clearfix not resolving thumbnail spacing issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Very new to what it means for things to "float" in the Bootstrap grid and `clearfix`. I was under the mistaken impression that if my col-{viewport size}-* made sense, everything would more or less fall into place. I was wrong.

I the markup below, I have a series of thumbnails with Bootstrap classes setup for xs, sm, md, and lg screens. At screen widths <= 1190px, I get a row of three images, followed by one row for "Game of Fifteen", and a row of three images. Adding a `clearfix` tag above "Game of Fifteen" fixed the issue at this size, but then as the viewport grew smaller, the same thing happened with the "Finder" image. `Clearfix` resolve this second issue. How can I resolve this such that everything is displayed as my `col-` class designations indicate I'd like it rendered?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap Links -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .navbar, .about, .contact {
                background-color: #003399;
                color: white;
            }

            .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
                color: white;
                font-size: 25px;
            }


            .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            #chicago-pic {
                margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
            }

            ul {
                padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            img {
                max-height: 200px;
            }

            .portfolio {
                background-color: #808080;
                color: white;
            }

            .form-control {
                margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
            }

            .control-label {
                margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
            }

            .thumbnail {
                margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            }

            button {
                margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
            }

            #copyright {
                margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-static-top">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Coder</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#about-section">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio-section">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact-section">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
        </nav> <!-- navbar-default-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="about row">
                <a href="#" name="about-section"></a>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                    <h1>About</h1>
                    <h2>Stuff</h2>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <ul id="skills-left" class="skills">
                            <li>Back-End Development (Flask)</li>
                            <li>Database Design and Implementation (PostgreSQL)</li>
                            <li>Agile Development</li>
                        </ul> <!-- skills left -->
                    </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <ul id="skills-right" class="skills">
                            <li>Python</li>
                            <li>Javascript/jQuery</li>
                            <li>SQL</li>
                            <li>C</li>
                        </ul> <!-- skills right -->
                    </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->
                </div> <!-- col-md-10 -->
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <img id="chicago-pic" class="img-responsive" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500487003906-9baadc8d610d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&s=0222b085d402a1b7be8c65bbcec574bb' alt='Chicago'>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- about section and row -->
            <div class="portfolio row" name="portfolio-section">
                <a href="#" name="portfolio-section"></a>
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="https://codepen.io/rcd1693/full/zwQGQW/" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/TributePage.png" alt="Tribute Page">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            Tribute Page (HTML/CSS/Bootstrap)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/blob/master/PSET2-Cryptography/caesar.py" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/caesar.jpg" alt="caesar">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            Caesar Cipher (Python)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET3-Finder-GameOf15/find" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/haystack.jpg" alt="needle in haystack">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            Finder (C)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/blob/master/PSET3-Finder-GameOf15/fifteen/fifteen.c" class="thumbnail">
                        <img style="max-height:200px" src="img/15.png" alt="number fifteen">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            Game of Fifteen (C)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET6-Sentiment/Sentiment" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/sentiment.jpg" alt="sentiment">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            Twitter Sentiment Analyzer (Python/NLTK)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET7-CS50Finance/finance" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/business.jpg" alt="quotes">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            CS50 Finance Trading Website (HTML/CSS/Bootstrap/PostgresSQL/Python)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET8-Mashup/mashup" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/map.jpg" alt="map">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            Mashup (Javascript/SQL/GoogleMaps API/Python)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- portfolio section and row -->
            <div class="contact row">
                <a href="#" name="contact-section"></a>
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <form action="https://formspree.io/example@domain.com" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label text-right">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xl-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First and Last Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <label for="_replyto" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label text-right">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xl-9">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="_replyto" placeholder="example@domain.com" required>
                        </div>
                        <label for="message" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label text-right">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xl-9">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                  </div> <!-- form group -->
                </div> <!-- col-md-8 -->
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <h3>For further information concerning the above portfolio samples or opportunities based on related
                    technologies, send me a note using the form to your left.</h3>
            </div> <!-- contact section and row -->
            <div class="footer row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                    <p id="copyright">&copy; 2017 Coder<p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- container fluid -->

        <!-- Boostrap Links -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is meant to be built on rows with 12 columns by default. Your `.portfolio.row` has way more than 12 columns. You should wrap every 12 columns in a `.row` if you want it to behave correctly - unless you set the same static height on all the columns.

Comment: Right. And that was my initial design, which contemplated only col-md-* screens. But I wanted to add responsivity for mobile, tablets, etc. So, for example, when viewed on mobile or tablet, I wanted only two thumbnails across, while on a medium screen I wanted 3 thumbnails across. From what I researched, this was the was to get that effect. Is there an alternate approach you could recommend?

Comment: Well you can do it this way you would just have to set a static height on all the columns in the portfolio row. Is that something you can do for this project? (see the "quotes" column wraps to 2 lines of text making it taller then the rest)

Comment: Yes, I can do whatever I wish on this. It's a personal page. I'd just like the design to be respectable. I'll play around with that approach.

Comment: You can also look into making your own layout for that section using `flexbox`. It works very well in these situations. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/61ysa0x4/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving what you want without setting static heights on all your Bootstraps columns is to make it a `flexbox` layout. It would just require a flexbox container around all of your Bootstrap columns contents (I just unwrapped all the columns).

Like this:

```
  <div class="portfolio-container">
     <a href="https://codepen.io/rcd1693/full/zwQGQW/" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/TributePage.png" alt="Tribute Page">
        <div class="caption text-center">
          Tribute Page (HTML/CSS/Bootstrap)
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/blob/master/PSET2-Cryptography/caesar.py" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/caesar.jpg" alt="caesar">
        <div class="caption text-center">
          Caesar Cipher (Python)
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET3-Finder-GameOf15/find" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/haystack.jpg" alt="needle in haystack">
        <div class="caption text-center">
          Finder (C)
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/blob/master/PSET3-Finder-GameOf15/fifteen/fifteen.c" class="thumbnail">
        <img style="max-height:200px" src="img/15.png" alt="number fifteen">
        <div class="caption text-center">
          Game of Fifteen (C)
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET6-Sentiment/Sentiment" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/sentiment.jpg" alt="sentiment">
        <div class="caption text-center">
          Twitter Sentiment Analyzer (Python/NLTK)
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET7-CS50Finance/finance" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/business.jpg" alt="quotes">
        <div class="caption text-center">
          CS50 Finance Trading Website (HTML/CSS/Bootstrap/PostgresSQL/Python)
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/ryan-christopher/HarvardCS50/tree/master/PSET8-Mashup/mashup" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/map.jpg" alt="map">
        <div class="caption text-center">
          Mashup (Javascript/SQL/GoogleMaps API/Python)
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Then some styles:

```
.portfolio-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.portfolio-container > * {
  width: calc(33% - 10px); /* -10px to account for left and right margins*/
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .portfolio-container > * {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

See a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/61ysa0x4/2/).